# What is the MsgBox font/font size used in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

What is the Font and Font Size used inside a standard `MsgBox` dialog in VBA for Excel?

When I search for that here in S.O. I am not seeing anything useful, and certainly not the answer to this specific question.  The bulk of the questions/answers all revolve around generating a custom user form with whatever font a user wants because a user wants a custom dialog with a different size. . .

I'm specifically trying to find what Font/Size is used on the standard `MsgBox` so I can create a custom form which *matches* the same Font/Size of a standard `MsgBox` but this answer eludes me . . .

I have seen it referenced as "The Windows Default Font" . . . if this is the case, *where* do I find it, and can it be programmatically referenced in VBA?  I'm sure this may change from user to user.  It appears on my system to be `Tahoma` `size 8`, but even this does not match exact, and this may not be the same as everyone else's PC. . . Also, I'm only guessing by painstakingly matching it one step at a time.

I have tried looking under `Application` which does not provide any `Font` Class, and `Windows` just gives me the options for the `Application.Windows` Class.

If this is a duplicate question and this has already been asked, please point me to it and I will gladly peruse it.

Update:
I'm looking into the Win32 API's based on [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215988/determine-windows-system-wide-font) and have found some options pointing to the message fonts (as suggested by the comment to this question) and am developing something like the following.  Am I close?

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Long) As Long

Const SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS as long= &H29
'Not sure if the SystemParameterInfo Function requires Hex or Decimal value for NONCLIENTMETRICS construct.
'Const SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS as long = 41
```

Then my next question is how to point to the `lfMessagefont` type from the
`NONCLIENTMETRICS` construct to obtain that `LOGFONT` data. . .  Microsoft docs don't specify in ways that are making sense to me . . . yet.

[NONCLIENTMETRICSA Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-nonclientmetricsa)
[LOGFONTA Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfonta)

As "Cool" as it would be. . .  I'm starting to believe it'll be MUCH simpler just to make a custom form as everyone else does. . .

Comment: Isn't that the same as windows message boxes? I have a feeling it's actually windows that does the message box and not excel/VBA.

Comment: Sure - it may be - where is this size determined though, and, can this be referenced via VBA?  If there's a Windows API that could reference this, this might be the way to go

Comment: Updated the question to include the rabbit trail I just endured looking at Windows API info to find the windows message box font info and my brain is exploding.